# error CS0039: Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.Object' to `SWS.PathWayPoints' via a built-in conversion

Tags: c#, unity3d, сериализация

Ошибка в строчке :

```
PathWayPoints tempPathWayPoints = m_pathWayPoints.objectReferenceValue as PathWayPoints;
```

У меня есть PathManager :

```
namespace SWS
{
    public class PathManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
     ...
     [HideInInspector]
        public PathWayPoints pathWayPoints;
     ...
    }
}
```

PathWayPoints:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace SWS
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class PathWayPoints {

        [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
        public List<Vector3> points;

        public PathWayPoints(Vector3 centre)
        {
            points = new List<Vector3>
            {
                centre+Vector3.left,
                centre+(Vector3.left+Vector3.forward)*.5f,
                centre + (Vector3.right+Vector3.back)*.5f,
                centre + Vector3.right
            };
        }

        public Vector3 this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                return points[i];
            }
        }

        public int NumPoints
        {
            get
            {
                return points.Count;
            }
        }

        public int NumSegments
        {
            get
            {
                return (points.Count - 4) / 3 + 1;
            }
        }

        public void AddSegment(Vector3 anchorPos)
        {
            points.Add(points[points.Count - 1] * 2 - points[points.Count - 2]);
            points.Add((points[points.Count - 1] + anchorPos) * .5f);
            points.Add(anchorPos);
        }

        public Vector3[] GetPointsInSegment(int i)
        {
            return new Vector3[] { points[i * 3], points[i * 3 + 1], points[i * 3 + 2], points[i * 3 + 3] };
        }

        public void MovePoint(int i, Vector3 pos)
        {
            Vector3 deltaMove = pos - points[i];
            points[i] = pos;

            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                if (i + 1 < points.Count)
                {
                    points[i + 1] += deltaMove;
                }
                if (i - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    points[i - 1] += deltaMove;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bool nextPointIsAnchor = (i + 1) % 3 == 0;
                int correspondingControlIndex = (nextPointIsAnchor) ? i + 2 : i - 2;
                int anchorIndex = (nextPointIsAnchor) ? i + 1 : i - 1;

                if (correspondingControlIndex >= 0 && correspondingControlIndex < points.Count)
                {
                    float dst = (points[anchorIndex] - points[correspondingControlIndex]).magnitude;
                    Vector3 dir = (points[anchorIndex] - pos).normalized;
                    points[correspondingControlIndex] = points[anchorIndex] + dir * dst;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

И PathEditor:

```
namespace SWS
{

    [CustomEditor(typeof(PathManager))]
    public class PathEditor : Editor
    {
     ...
     private SerializedProperty m_pathWayPoints;
     PathWayPoints tempPathWayPoints;
     ...
     public void OnEnable()
     { 
       ...
       m_pathWayPoints = m_Object.FindProperty("pathWayPoints");
       var waypoints = GetWaypointArray();

       PathWayPoints tempPathWayPoints = m_pathWayPoints.objectReferenceValue as PathWayPoints; //ошибка error CS0039

            if (tempPathWayPoints == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        tempPathWayPoints = new PathWayPoints (waypoints [i].position);
                    } else {
                        tempPathWayPoints.AddSegment (waypoints [i].position);
                    }
                }
            }
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно было сделать класс PathWayPoints, наследником : MonoBehaviour

```
...
namespace SWS
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class PathWayPoints : MonoBehaviour {...}
...
}
```